# Change Output from Query

Tags: php, mysql

The flowing code outputs this result from my database

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING(UserID,45) FROM GridUser where Online ='True' "     );
if (!$result) {
die("query error");
}
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<table border='0'><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td><center>$cell</td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
}
    ?>
```

the out put from table looks like this

> hypergrid.org:8002/;Isolde Caron
>    with origional data looking like
>   '0012f478-60fe-49bf-bb2d-48a889191afd;http://hypergrid.org:8002/;Isolde Caron'

I wish to replace the ";" in the result with spaces...

any ideas would be greatly appreciated
tia
john

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str-replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo "<td><center>" . str_replace(';', ' ', $cell) . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simple replace the character:

```
echo "<td><center>" . str_replace(';', ' ', $cell) . "</td>";
```

NOTES:

- THe foreach is unnecesarry in your `while` loop, since row is a single row.
- Use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql functions, because mysql functions are deprecated.